# 10 days, still no confirmation. Will this ever get confirmed

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, transaction-verification

Hello StackExchange users,

I've been waiting for **10 days** now for my transaction to confirm, and it still hasn't. 
Can anyone please tell me if there is something I can do, or what the status of my transaction is? 
All I know is this https://blockchain.info/address/3QG9MtXed7gJXAoLfMGFH2comrhN84hVk4 
- But I don't understand much about it...

Thanks alot for any feedback and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Your fees are 17 sat/byte which is very low. I’d recommend using the “replace by fee” feature to accelerate the confirmation speed.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. How / where do I use the replace by fee feature? I'm using GreenAdress as wallet. Thanks again.

Comment: [Here is an article](http://coinour.com/index.php/how-to-apply-replace-by-fee-to-save-the-bitcoin-transaction-fees/) on how to use RBF on GreenAddress. Note: this took me one minute on Google. Search engines can solve your problems faster than StackExchange in a lot of cases.